# How do I obtain offline tokens in Microsoft Authentication Library (MSAL) for .NET?

Tags: xamarin, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-msal

I have a Xamarin.Forms iOS/Android app and have to authenticate the user against a Microsoft Azure B2C AD.

I have added the Microsoft.Identity.Client NuGet and using this for authentication.

Login works fine and I am able to use the returned token to call an Azure hosted service of our own.

The app needs to work offline also and from what I understand from [Azure AD B2C preview: Token reference](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/active-directory-b2c-reference-tokens) I should be able to obtain a "refresh token" with longer life-span if I provide the scope `offline_access`.

However, if I do provide this scope, the library throws an exception that `offline_access` is not supported.

My question is: is this because the MSAL currently does not support `offline_access` at all or am I supposed to obtain the same in a different manner?

Comment: I would be very interested in this as well, for a UWP application scenario.

Answer (score 0):

I use `Microsoft.Experimental.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory` for this which you can install from Package Manager console with

```
install-package Microsoft.Experimental.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory -pre
```

Samples:

- https://github.com/KaiWalter/B2C-NativeClient-Xamarin
- https://github.com/KaiWalter/B2C-NativeClient-WindowsPhone8.1

I guess one of the samples can also be applied to UWP